# Run click function using url

Tags: jquery, html, href

I have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
            var austDay = new Date(2013, 10-1, 20, 10, 30);
            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    });

    $(".view").click(function() {
        $("#popup").bPopup({
    easing: 'easeOutBack',
        speed: 600,
        transition: 'slideDown'
        });
    });

});
```

which is in a file called index.html

I would like to run this part when the HTML is loading:

```
 $(".view").click(function() {
        $("#popup").bPopup({
    easing: 'easeOutBack',
        speed: 600,
        transition: 'slideDown'
        });
});
```

What do I need to write after the `index.html`?

Comment: is the popup not working???` $(".view").trigger('click')` can trigger the click event

Comment: $(".view").click() will run while you click the `.view` if you want to run with out click mean write anonymous function

Comment: the popup works good. i would like to run the script when the page load without changing the code at the HTML file but only by add code to the url that leads to the HTML. is this possible?

Comment: @user2833981: Have you tried my code? Isn't it working?

Answer (score 0):

Move the piece of code in a distinct Function, and call it anywhere you wish;

```
Function PopUp
{
 $("#popup").bPopup({
    easing: 'easeOutBack',
        speed: 600,
        transition: 'slideDown'
   });
}


$(".view").click(function() {
   PopUp();
 }


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function () {
            var austDay = new Date(2013, 10-1, 20, 10, 30);
            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    });

     PopUp();
    });

});
```

Comment: but then. how do i use
    $(".view").click(function() {
     PopUp();
      }
via url?

Comment: Call the PopUp function directly `href="javascript:PopUp()"`

Comment: Check [link on how to call function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736248/can-url-tell-jquery-to-run-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add one line at the end:

i.e. `$('.view').trigger('click');`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(function () {
                var austDay = new Date(2013, 10-1, 20, 10, 30);
                $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
        });

        $(".view").click(function() {
            $("#popup").bPopup({
        easing: 'easeOutBack',
            speed: 600,
            transition: 'slideDown'
            });
        });
       $('.view').trigger('click');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it, don't use "click" method.

You can't use #popup when HTML is loading, because... #popup probably doesn't exist. It's loaded with HTML.

But if you want to load it after HTML is loaded, just put it in:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#popup").bPopup({
            easing: 'easeOutBack',
            speed: 600,
            transition: 'slideDown'
           });
    });
</script>
```

instead of putting it in click function.